# C# BouncyCastle Mac check in GCM failed Error when used Tag as Base 64 String

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, aes-gcm

I am trying to implement a AES 256 encryption with GCM using BouncyCastle library.

So far I have managed to make it work by passing `Key and Nonce` as string and `Tag` as byte array.

This is the encryption method.

```cs
private static byte[] EncryptWithGCM(string plaintext, string KeyString, string NonceString, byte[] tag)
{
    byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(KeyString);
    byte[] nonce = Convert.FromBase64String(NonceString);
        
    var plaintextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
    var bcCiphertext = new byte[plaintextBytes.Length + tagLenth];

    var cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesEngine());
    var parameters = new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(key), tagLenth * 8, nonce);
    cipher.Init(true, parameters);

    var offset = cipher.ProcessBytes(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length, bcCiphertext, 0);
    cipher.DoFinal(bcCiphertext, offset);
                    
    var ciphertext = new byte[plaintextBytes.Length];            
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bcCiphertext, 0, ciphertext, 0, plaintextBytes.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bcCiphertext, plaintextBytes.Length, tag, 0, tagLenth);

    return ciphertext;
}
```

and this is the decryption code.

```cs
private static string DecryptWithGCM(string EncryptedString, string KeyString, string NonceString, byte[] tag)
{
    byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(KeyString);
    byte[] nonce = Convert.FromBase64String(NonceString);
        
    byte[] ciphertext = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedString);
    var plaintextBytes = new byte[ciphertext.Length];

    var cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesEngine());
    var parameters = new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(key), tag.Length * 8, nonce);
    cipher.Init(false, parameters);

    var bcCiphertext = ciphertext.Concat(tag).ToArray();

    var offset = cipher.ProcessBytes(bcCiphertext, 0, bcCiphertext.Length, plaintextBytes, 0);
    cipher.DoFinal(plaintextBytes, offset);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintextBytes);
}
```

As you can see I am passing everything as string except the `Tag`. because when I pass the `Tag` as string and convert it to byte array it does not work. It shows error `"Mac check in GCM failed"`

So, this code works:

```cs
var rnd = new Random();
var tag = new Byte[16]; //16 bytes
rnd.NextBytes(tag);
string TagString = Convert.ToBase64String(tag);

byte[] EncryptedText = EncryptWithGCM(PlainText, KeyString, NonceString, tag);
string EncryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedText);
string DecryptdText = DecryptWithGCM(EncryptedString, KeyString, NonceString, tag);
```

But when I pass the TagString in the encryption/decryption functions and converting it back to byte array, it throws `"Mac check in GCM failed"` error.

```cs
// this code does not work.
private static string DecryptWithGCM(string EncryptedString, string KeyString, string NonceString, string TagString)
{
    byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(KeyString);
    byte[] nonce = Convert.FromBase64String(NonceString);
    byte[] tag = Convert.FromBase64String(TagString);
    ...
    ...
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag is *automatically* created during encryption and used during decryption to authenticate the data (in both cases in `DoFinal()`).
Since C#/BC *automatically* concatenates the tag with the ciphertext, the tag does not need to be passed *explicitly* during either encryption or decryption:

```cs
private static string EncryptWithGCM(string plaintext, string keyString, string nonceString)
{
    var tagLength = 16;
    var key = Convert.FromBase64String(keyString);
    var nonce = Convert.FromBase64String(nonceString);

    var plaintextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
    var ciphertextTagBytes = new byte[plaintextBytes.Length + tagLength];

    var cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesEngine());
    var parameters = new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(key), tagLength * 8, nonce);
    cipher.Init(true, parameters);

    var offset = cipher.ProcessBytes(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length, ciphertextTagBytes, 0);
    cipher.DoFinal(ciphertextTagBytes, offset); // create and append tag: ciphertext | tag

    return Convert.ToBase64String(ciphertextTagBytes);
}

private static string DecryptWithGCM(string ciphertextTag, string keyString, string nonceString)
{
    var tagLength = 16;
    var key = Convert.FromBase64String(keyString);
    var nonce = Convert.FromBase64String(nonceString);
    
    var ciphertextTagBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertextTag);
    var plaintextBytes = new byte[ciphertextTagBytes.Length - tagLength];

    var cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesEngine());
    var parameters = new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(key), tagLength * 8, nonce);
    cipher.Init(false, parameters);

    var offset = cipher.ProcessBytes(ciphertextTagBytes, 0, ciphertextTagBytes.Length, plaintextBytes, 0); 
    cipher.DoFinal(plaintextBytes, offset); // authenticate data via tag

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintextBytes);
}
```

Note that with a fixed key, a static nonce is a *fatal* bug for GCM ([here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26790)). The (non-secret) nonce should be randomly generated and passed to the decrypting side along with the ciphertext and tag (typically concatenated in the following order: nonce | ciphertext | tag).